# command, concat and format the result of multiple list

Tags: command-line

I search 2 things

1. how to concat the result of command in a file.
2. how to format the result of NET in html like the /format of wmic

I want to create a command (in a bat file) for getting information of a VM.

Sample :

```
I use wmic and NET.

wmic product get Name,Vendor,Version,Description,InstallDate /format:htable > VM_info.html

NET LOCALGROUP Administrators > VM_info.html
```

The result is an html file with both list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/format:htable` functionality is provided built-in with `wmic`. `wmic` provides it while the `NET` commands do not. So, formatting the output of `NET LOCALGROUP` as `<html>` isn't possible unless you write a custom program for that.

But, to concat the results of one command to another is quite simple:

```
wmic product get Name,Vendor,Version,Description,InstallDate /format:htable > VM_info.html
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators >> VM_info.html
```

Notice the **>>** used in the second command.
That's what appends the output instead of overwriting the file.